# Laravel validation unique rule reflection class exception

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to setup a unique rule for an email address field and I'm running into a ReflectionException because the validation table name is being cast into a class. Looking at the documentation this should just cast it to the table however..

Laravel version is: 5.7.

The validation rules are like this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'unique:users',
    'password' => 'same:password_confirmation'
]);
```

Where $this is the Controller, I've also tried using the Illuminate\Http\Request; same result.

The stacktrace that I get is the following:

```
ReflectionException thrown with message "Class users does not exist"

Stacktrace:
#65 ReflectionException in /var/www/vendor/laravel-doctrine/orm/src/IlluminateRegistry.php:362
#64 ReflectionClass:__construct in /var/www/vendor/laravel-doctrine/orm/src/IlluminateRegistry.php:362
#63 LaravelDoctrine\ORM\IlluminateRegistry:getManagerForClass in /var/www/vendor/laravel-doctrine/orm/src/Validation/DoctrinePresenceVerifier.php:137
#62 LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Validation\DoctrinePresenceVerifier:getEntityManager in /var/www/vendor/laravel-doctrine/orm/src/Validation/DoctrinePresenceVerifier.php:93
#61 LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Validation\DoctrinePresenceVerifier:select in /var/www/vendor/laravel-doctrine/orm/src/Validation/DoctrinePresenceVerifier.php:46
#60 LaravelDoctrine\ORM\Validation\DoctrinePresenceVerifier:getCount in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php:687
#59 Illuminate\Validation\Validator:validateUnique in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:373
#58 Illuminate\Validation\Validator:validateAttribute in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:268
#57 Illuminate\Validation\Validator:passes in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:293
#56 Illuminate\Validation\Validator:fails in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:305
#55 Illuminate\Validation\Validator:validate in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.php:47
#54 App\Http\Controllers\Controller:validate in /var/www/app/Http/Controllers/SignUpController.php:74
#53 App\Http\Controllers\SignUpController:memberSignUp in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
#52 call_user_func_array in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
#51 Illuminate\Routing\Controller:callAction in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:45
#50 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher:dispatch in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:212
#49 Illuminate\Routing\Route:runController in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:169
#48 Illuminate\Routing\Route:run in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:679
#47 Illuminate\Routing\Router:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
#46 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/app/Http/Middleware/BoxMiddleware.php:28
#45 App\Http\Middleware\BoxMiddleware:handle in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#44 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#43 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:41
#42 Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings:handle in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#41 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#40 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:75
#39 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken:handle in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#38 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#37 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php:49
#36 Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession:handle in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#35 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#34 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:63
#33 Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession:handle in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#32 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#31 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:37
#30 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse:handle in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#29 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#28 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:66
#27 Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies:handle in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#26 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#25 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:104
#24 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:681
#23 Illuminate\Routing\Router:runRouteWithinStack in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:656
#22 Illuminate\Routing\Router:runRoute in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:622
#21 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:611
#20 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:176
#19 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
#18 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php:57
#17 Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies:handle in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#16 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#15 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:31
#14 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#13 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#12 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:31
#11 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest:handle in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#10 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27
#8 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize:handle in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#7 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#6 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:62
#5 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode:handle in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:151
#4 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
#3 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:104
#2 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:then in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:151
#1 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:sendRequestThroughRouter in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:116
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:handle in /var/www/public/index.php:55
```

I might just be overlooking something, however after one hour of debugging I decided to post a question. Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you Add your Controller?

Comment: can u post `composer.json` content?

Comment: are you sure `users` table is exist?

Answer (score 0):

In type of using laravel-doctrine, the validation accept two parameter:

As [Documentation](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.3/orm/validation) Says:

```
/**
 * Store a new blog post.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|unique:App\User,username',
    ]);
}
```

therefore in your case:

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|unique:App\User,email',
    ]);
```

Comment: The weird thing is, is that I'm not actually using Doctrine. I don't have the laravel-doctrine dependency anywhere.

Comment: @JKaan, let's see your Stacktrace again. because of that i suggest this solution.

Comment: @JKaan, check `'doctrine_presence_verifier' => false`, in `doctrine.php`, it must set to false.

Comment: @Moshen, I do not even seem to have a doctrine.php. This should be in the config directory I presume?

Comment: @JKaan, I checked your problem again, if you use Eloquent try to removed "laravel-doctrine" package else , use my solution.

Comment: I posted the answer that solved my solution! Thanks for your time Mohsen

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar perfect answer, should be standalone!

Answer (score 0):

What fixed my issue was the following:

I still had a part of the `laravel-doctrine/orm` left in my vendor folder probably because I removed the dependency but never ran composer to reflect those changes. Therefore running `composer install` fixed my issue!

Comment: The other suggestion from Mohsen Shakibafar (in the comments) fixed it for me :)